# I am trying to pass the arguments a and b to the local function "isPrimes" to be used as a range

Tags: python-3.x

If I try to run the `isPrime` function on it's own -- replacing `n` with any integer, it will find if it is a prime number or not; but getting `a` and `b` from `primes` to be used as the range of numbers to check if they are prime is where the issue lies .

```
def primes(a,b):
    pass

def isPrime(n):
    # I want to make n take the values of a and b so that the is Prime
    # function executes all the prime numbers within the range a to b
    if n == 1:
        return False
    # here I've tried referencing n and (a,b) as the range but neither
    # option does anything
    for z in range(a, b):
        if n % z == 0:
            return False
    else:
        # this is supposed to print the n each time it comes up as a prime
        # number but when I run this nothing happens and I'm not sure where
        # I'm going wrong
        print(n)
        return True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Switch the order of your return and print statement. Your program is
   ending before your print statement executes
2. If you want to specify a range for which you are going to test if a
   number is prime, you will either have to declare a and b in your
   function, or pass it in as a parameter.
3. In your range statement, for each integer from a to b, but you are returning false whenever n%z = 0. This will occur for when you attempt to use the % operator on a prime with a prime (ex. 17 % 17 would return false). add a statement to compare if n != z.
4. You return false in your if statement, and true in your else statement. This means your code will only make one comparison before your function will exit. Add your return true statement at the end of your program.

see below:

```
def isPrime(n):
    a = 2
    b = 100000

    if n == 1:
        print("1 is not a prime number.")
        return False

    for z in range(a,b):  
        if n%z==0 and n != z:
            print(str(n) + " is not a prime number.")
            return False

    print(str(n) + " is a prime number.")
    return True
```